# Ubuntu virtualbox failing to start

Tags: boot, virtualbox, docker

I have been running Ubuntu 20.04 inside VirtualBox (version 6.0.6) on my W10 host PC. Things were fine the other day, but now I have something along the lines of the following message when I try to start it up:

```
/dev/sda5: recovering journal
*ERROR* Failed to send host log message
```

I have allocated 8GB RAM and 4 CPUs to it, and when I set vbox up I gave it 25GB storage. My Graphics controller is set to VMSVGA but I have tried changing it to VBoxVGA as well as VBoxSVGA, neither of which worked. I also tried disabling 3D Acceleration, all to no avail.

It was pretty new with very little installed.. However, I was trying to learn Apache Airflow using Docker, so I have a few things set up for that, but I was only following a tutorial with not a lot of space used. When I last logged on I noticed that I had a space warning, which I was very strange because I can't have possbly used up the remaining 15GB storage (accounting for 10GB for the OS)! Could Docker have caused this problem?

I'm quite in the dark as I'm very new to ubuntu, virtualbox, and never used docker in the past.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502540/

Comment: Yes, I had seen this question (and others like it) but these did not solve my problem.

Comment: There are so many disparate answers out there that I suspect there is no single cause for this error message. You out-of-space message is the only real clue, which may (or may not) be related to the Virtualbox problem. Boot from your install .iso (not the installed virtual HDD), enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment, and see what's taking up all the space on the virtual HDD.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to boot from the install .iso. In the Storage window of the settings I added the .iso file which I used to set it up, it's under the Controller: SATA section. But when I hit F12 on booting up it isn't clear which I should select out of AHCI controller (hard disk), Other boot devices: (f) floppy, (c) CD rom, (l) LAN. I select CD ROM and it says `FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.`

Comment: It's the same way you originally installed Ubuntu: Insert the .iso into the Virtual CD drive.

Comment: Ok I tried this and apparently only 5.4gb is used in total. So I guess it isn't about space.